# How to make a command to change channel cooldown discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just wanted to ask how can i make a command, that will change channel sending messages cooldown. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slowmode_delay`.

No cogs:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True) # Permission to use command
async def slowmode(self, ctx, seconds: int): # seconds
     await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=seconds) # Edits the channel, (slowmode_delay = channel slowmode.
     await ctx.send(f"I've set the slowmode to **{seconds}** seconds in {ctx.channel.mention}!") # Message sent after the slowmode is set.
```

Cogs:

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def slowmode(self, ctx, seconds: int):
     await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=seconds)
     await ctx.send(f"I've set the slowmode to **{seconds}** seconds in {ctx.channel.mention}!")
```

[Command Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsoG6.png)